# Lambda function to decrypt files, adds the required metadata and sends them to S3 bucket

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, amazon-s3, amazon-efs

I need to write a File decryption lambda function which will get executed when a new file lands to the EFS. This can use Cloudwatch events when the final trigger file is copied.The function picks up the encrypted file, decrypts them, adds the required metadata and sends them to the S3 bucket.

Please provide me links so that I can go through and read few blogs before start writing Lambda function

Comment: Lambda functions do not have access to EFS.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot.. What is the suggestible solution for this.

Comment: You'd need to access EFS from servers running in EC2.   Lambda containers don't currently support this.  Note also that Stack Overflow is not really intended for questions asking for an off-site article, resource, or how-to on getting started with a task: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: Thank you @Michael-sqlbot.. Could you let me know any Forum where I can shoot this question